# How to turn on video recording problematically in android

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there any way to turn on the camera and start recording the scene and stop it after programmatically?
I googled on this but could not get any helpful info. Please help.

Comment: on which context you need to start recording the scene?

Comment: Simply on `OnClickListener` of a button in my app's main activity

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes [Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) is more time saving than looking for code snippets on the web.